# Как активировать пользователя после подтверждения почты?

Tags: django

Я делаю регистрацию на сайте через отправку кода на почту, когда пользователь вводит данные создается неактивный пользователь, потом его перекидывает на страницу ввода кода. Мне нужно что бы после того как он ввел правильный код, сделать юзера активным(все остальное робит). Как это можно сделать?

views.py

```
def registr(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Registr(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        

        subject = 'Код подтверждения'
        code = regCode()
        message = code

        request.session['code'] = message
        from_email = 'my_email@gmail.com'
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')

        mail = send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [email], fail_silently=False)

        if mail:
            messages.success(request, 'Письмо с кодом отправлено')
            return redirect('conf-page')
            if conf():
                return redirect('reg-page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка отправки')
        
                
else:
    form = Registr()

return render(request, 'users/registr.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Регистрация', 'news': news})

def conf(request):


if request.method == 'POST':
    
    if form.is_valid():
        code = request.session['code']
        code_user = form.cleaned_data.get('cnf')
        
        if str(code_user) == code:

            messages.success(request, 'Вы зареганы!')
            return redirect('login-page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Коды не совпадают!')
    


return render(request, 'users/conf.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Подтверждение почты', 'news': news})
```

forms.py

```
class Registr(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Registr, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs\
        .update({
            'placeholder': 'Придумайте себе имя',
            'class': 'form-control form-inp input-lg'
        })
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs\
        .update({
            'placeholder': 'Ваш email',
            'class': 'form-control form-inp input-lg'
        })
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs\
        .update({
            'placeholder': 'Придумайте пароль',
            'class': 'form-control form-inp input-lg'
        })
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs\
        .update({
            'placeholder': 'Повторите пароль',
            'class': 'form-control input-lg'
        })

 class Confirm(forms.Form):
      cnf = forms.IntegerField(label='Введите код', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-lg'}))

      class Meta:
          fields = ['cnf']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну вы можете передать какой-нибудь идентификатор этого пользователя еще в сессии вместе с кодом. Например `id` и потом сделать так.
в `def registr(request):` добавить
user_name = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
request.session['name'] = user_name
и в  `def conf`

```
session_user_name = request.session['name']
if str(code_user) == code:
    user = User.objects.get(username=session_user_name)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()

    messages.success(request, 'Вы зареганы!')
    return redirect('login-page')
```

Comment: Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите как это сделать, я еще новичек в django и не понимаю(

Comment: @ЛехаТуз а код выше ваш?

Comment: да, это мой код

Comment: @ЛехаТуз ну так тогда в чем проблема? вы передаете сообщение в сессии и с этим справились. Просто добавьте еще и передачу id пользователя

Comment: у меня в моделе нет поля 'id'..

Comment: @ЛехаТуз она по умолчанию есть у любой модели.

Comment: я пробовал получить id: id = form.cleaned_data.get('id'), а потом передать это через request.session, но выдает ошибку 'Запрос на сопоставление пользователей не существует.'

Comment: @ЛехаТуз немного дополни ответ. Попробуйте. `form.cleaned_data.get('id')` берет значения с полей формы

Comment: @ЛехаТуз добавьте свою форму и модель. Если хотите получить более полный ответ

Comment: у меня модели отсутствуют, но формы добавил

Comment: @ЛехаТуз добавил правку

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все заработало!